# Using Maps API and Geolocation in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way to embed or implement somehow Geolocation (via GPS or whatever method) and using maps from Google Maps or OSM in applications using libgdx?
I can't find APIs or documentation regarding this, to implement an application using real world maps and Augmented Reality.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use Google Maps V2 Api with libgdx. You can use Markers, get Location and display it in a Scene2d Label, also you can show or hide the map.

I wrote example code [Github](https://github.com/Tiarsoft/GoogleMapsLibgdx)

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never?

I have started to implement such an extension for Libgd with open street maps. It does currently load, cache and render the map tiles. You are also able to zoom, and pan the map. In future updates searching for geo locations will also be possible.

Github: https://github.com/aspic/libgdx-maps

Comment: Hey I think your project is very interesting, but I couldn't test it because it's missing the assets. Also, pick a [license](http://blog.codinghorror.com/pick-a-license-any-license/)!