# libGDX open a map through a button

Tags: android, gps, libgdx

I'm trying to make a button that will open a map (GPS) that will show you a specific place.
I have no idea how to open a map through libGDX, if someone knows anything like that please answer me.

Comment: Your question is too broad and doesn't show any research effort. What have you already tried ? What is not working ? In this state, this question can't be answered.

Comment: What's this have to do with dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

At first you should think a bit more about your project. 
I suggest also that you split your main goal in smaller parts. 
Instead of creating a button which opens a map.

- Create a Button
- Create a ClickListener
- What kind of a map do you want do show?

Decide if it's a map file or your current position on a map.
And then you'll know what you need. And then you can google.

Good Luck!

Comment: i use libgdx, so i got a button, and a button listener, i can open links if i press a button, its all working fine, i want that when i press my button a map from google will open and i will see directions how to get to a place

Comment: Hey, sorry I don't know anything about libgdx and a google maps implementation. The only thing I found was **[this Stackoverflow Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145254/using-maps-api-and-geolocation-in-libgdx)**. There is a example for a google maps api integration and a open street maps for libgdx widget.
I hope that will help.